# Join a Sub-Query in EF Core

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-core, common-table-expression, window-functions

Goal: I want to select the latest versioned records of a given table:

| id | version | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | Alek |
| 1 | 1 | Alex |
| 2 | 0 | Bob |

Note: the temporal data feature is a no-go.

Ideally this is what I want EF Core to generate using CTE's:

```sql
WITH cte (Id, Version) AS 
(
    SELECT 
        Id, MAX(Version)
    FROM 
        Table
    GROUP BY 
        Id
)
SELECT a.*
FROM Table a
JOIN cte ON a.Id = cte.Id AND cte.Version = e.Version;
```

Note: here is an alternative but equivalent query if the above is impossible in EF Core:

```sql
SELECT a.*
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY Version DESC) rn
    FROM Table a
    WHERE redacted
) a
WHERE a.rn = 1;
```

C# LINQ query:

```cs
var query = (from a in context.Test
            join j in (from m in context.Test
                        group m by m.Id
                        into g
                        select new { g.Key, Version = g.Max(x => x.Version) })
            on new { a.Id, a.Version } equals new { Id = j.Key, j.Version } into gj
            select a).ToQueryString();
```

**ISSUE**: the actual generated SQL query completely misses the sub-query:

```sql
SELECT [a].[Id], [a].[Version]
FROM [Employer] AS [e]
```

Comment: Which version of EF Core are you using?

Comment: [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore) + [Linq To DB CTE](https://linq2db.github.io/articles/sql/CTE.html) = profit!

Comment: Side note: your alternative `ROW_NUMBER` query is almost certainly the most efficient.

Comment: If you  `select gj` instead at the end I suspect the query would reflect the joins. EF is likely optimizing it out since you aren't selecting based on it at all and the join may be getting interpretted as an outer elationship, hence optional based on selecting "a".

Comment: @PeterBergman I'm using EF Core 7.

Answer (score 1):

The most correct way to do a row-number query in EF Core is to let it work that out for itself

```cs
var query = 
    context.Test
    .GroupBy(t => t.Id)
    .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(t => t.Version).First());
```

I'm not sure why the joined query wasn't working, but it's not very efficient anyway.

Comment: Ok fixed that..

Comment: Yes I thought of returning the (Id, Version) tuple and passing it into another query to get the dependent data i.e. Name but that would be two return trips to the DB (inefficient). The answer is a solution albeit an inefficient one :).

Comment: What is inefficient about this? It is normally translated to `ROW_NUMBER` which is very efficient.

Comment: The communication between application and database over the network is expensive. Your solution returns `(Id, Version)` but not `(Id, Version, Name, etc.)` so it would require a second DB trip. The question details provides two raw SQL examples of a 1-DB-trip solution.

Comment: No that's not true, it's not returning the group, it's selecting the whole object, the top 1 per group. Try it and see what it returns.